# onclick cancel button still calls ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Button onclick looks like this `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')"`. Even though the cancel is clicked the post is still deleted.

Then in the jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
        $a = $(this).text().trim();
        if ($a == "Delete") 
        {
            var postid = $(this).next('.postid').val();
            $(this).closest(".todo-content").fadeOut('slow');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: BASE_URL+'classes/deletepost',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {postid: postid},
                async: false,
                success: function( data ) {
              },
              error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                  // check status && error
            }
      });
        }
    });
});
```

Is there anyway to cancel the calling to the ajax if the cancel in the confirmation is clicked?

Comment: I'd recommend not using the button's text to determine its behavior.  Also, don't use synchronous Ajax.

Comment: yeah i fixed it already. forgot to delete the question lol. i guess i still have to choose the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply move from events in 2 places to one? Move the confirm out of the HTML and put it in your javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(event){
       if (!confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?'))
         return;

       event.preventDefault(); 
       /* code to delete here */
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, You can use it like this

In the Ajax function after {event.preventDefault();}
This line add below

if(!confirm("Are you sure")) return;

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to include the confirm in your javascript instead of inline.

```
$('.btn').click(function(event){
if(!confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?'))
return;
    event.preventDefault(); 
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick` completely, and structure your code within a function:

```
function deleteItem() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?')) {
        // code to delete...
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(event){
        deleteItem();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to cancel the calling to the ajax if the cancel in the
>   confirmation is clicked?

Yes, that is possible. You could put the result from the `confirm` in a variable:

```
onclick="doDelete=confirm('Are you sure to delete this item?');"
```

In the jQuery code you can check the value of the variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (doDelete) {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

However, being possible doesn't mean that it's the best solution. The most obvious solution would be to do the `confirm` call in the jQuery code instead.